# How to add a onclick pop up form on a page?

Tags: shopify, shopify-template

When someone clicks on a button then a pop up form will appear.
I am trying to do but don't know how to fix it.

Answer (score 0):

You can open new popup window form by javascript as you have to
call following with onclick event of your button

```
window.open(url, 'new tab', 'width=700,height=500');
```

You can also close this popup window after success of form submission by following

```
window.close(url);
```

In url you have to add your url.
If this is not work please share more information. thank you